# Handle ASP.NET WebSocket connections using TPL Dataflow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, tpl-dataflow

I was recently introduced to the wonders of TPL Dataflow and thought it would be a good exercise to create a wrapper class which wraps around an ASP.NET `WebSocket` object and processes the input and output streams using dataflow blocks, to make it easy to pipe inbound and outbound messages to data processing pipelines.

To keep things simple, this wrapper buffers received messages in full before passing them, which I believe is similar to how the JavaScript WebSocket API in the browser works. To prevent enormous messages from tanking the server, you can specify `maxReceivedMessageSize`.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace WebSocketSample
{
    public sealed class DataflowWebSocketConnection : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly WebSocket _webSocket;
        private readonly int _maxReceivedMessageSize;
        private readonly CancellationToken _connectionAbortedToken;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _sendingAbortedCts;

        private readonly BufferBlock<(WebSocketMessageType Type, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Data)> _receiveBlock;
        private readonly ActionBlock<(WebSocketMessageType Type, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Data)> _sendBlock;
        private readonly WriteOnceBlock<(WebSocketCloseStatus Code, string? Reason)> _closeBlock;

        private readonly Task _webSocketClosure;

        public DataflowWebSocketConnection(
            WebSocket webSocket,
            int maxReceivedMessageSize,
            CancellationToken connectionAbortedtoken)
        {
            _webSocket = webSocket;
            _maxReceivedMessageSize = maxReceivedMessageSize;
            _connectionAbortedToken = connectionAbortedtoken;
            _sendingAbortedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(_connectionAbortedToken);

            _receiveBlock = new BufferBlock<(WebSocketMessageType Type, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Data)>(
                new DataflowBlockOptions { CancellationToken = _connectionAbortedToken });

            _sendBlock = new ActionBlock<(WebSocketMessageType Type, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Data)>(
                x => SendMessageAsync(x.Type, x.Data),
                new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { CancellationToken = _sendingAbortedCts.Token });

            _closeBlock = new WriteOnceBlock<(WebSocketCloseStatus Code, string? Reason)>(
                cloningFunction: null,
                new DataflowBlockOptions { CancellationToken = _connectionAbortedToken });

            _webSocketClosure = Task.WhenAll(ReceiveMessagesAsync(), SendMessagesAsync());
        }

        public ISourceBlock<(WebSocketMessageType Type, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Data)> Input => _receiveBlock;

        public ITargetBlock<(WebSocketMessageType Type, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Data)> Output => _sendBlock;

        public Task Closure => _webSocketClosure;

        private async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync()
        {
            // NOTE: In practice, we use a rented buffer that starts off small but grows in size up until
            // '_maxReceivedMessageSize', but this has been simplified for the sake of brevity.

            using var receiveBufferOwner = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(_maxReceivedMessageSize);
            var receiveBuffer = receiveBufferOwner.Memory.Slice(0, _maxReceivedMessageSize);

            try
            {
                while (_webSocket.State < WebSocketState.Closed)
                {
                    var receiveResult = await _webSocket.ReceiveAsync(receiveBuffer, _connectionAbortedToken);

                    if (!receiveResult.EndOfMessage)
                    {
                        // We received a message that exceeded '_maxReceivedMessageSize' in size, so we should prepare
                        // to close the connection.

                        _ = _closeBlock.Post((WebSocketCloseStatus.MessageTooBig, null));

                        _receiveBlock.Complete();
                        _sendingAbortedCts.Cancel();

                        return;
                    }

                    if (_webSocket.State == WebSocketState.CloseReceived
                        && receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    {
                        // The remote endpoint started the closing handshake, so we should prepare to complete the
                        // closing handshake by echoing the message.

                        _ = _closeBlock.Post((_webSocket.CloseStatus!.Value, _webSocket.CloseStatusDescription));

                        _receiveBlock.Complete();
                        _sendingAbortedCts.Cancel();

                        return;
                    }

                    if (_webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                    {
                        // If the WebSocket is still open, continue posting messages to '_receiveBlock' as usual.

                        // NOTE: In practice, we use pooled memory and work with 'IMemoryOwner<byte>', but this has
                        // been replaced with a simple array allocation for the sake of brevity.

                        var messageData = new byte[receiveResult.Count];
                        receiveBuffer.Slice(0, receiveResult.Count).CopyTo(messageData);

                        _ = _receiveBlock.Post((receiveResult.MessageType, messageData));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _ = _closeBlock.Post((WebSocketCloseStatus.InternalServerError, null));

                ((IDataflowBlock)_receiveBlock).Fault(e);
                _sendingAbortedCts.Cancel();

                throw;
            }
        }

        private async Task SendMessagesAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await _sendBlock.Completion;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Attempt to set a close message indicating that a server error occurred.  If the exception caught is
                // an 'OperationCanceledException' that was thrown due to '_sendingAbortedCts' being canceled, a
                // different close message reflecting the actual reason for closure should have already been set, in
                // which case the below operation will do nothing.

                _ = _closeBlock.Post((WebSocketCloseStatus.InternalServerError, null));

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!_connectionAbortedToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // Attempt to close the connection gracefully.

                    var (code, reason) = await _closeBlock.ReceiveAsync(_connectionAbortedToken);

                    if (_webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                    {
                        await _webSocket.CloseAsync(code, reason, _connectionAbortedToken);
                    }
                    else if (_webSocket.State == WebSocketState.CloseReceived)
                    {
                        await _webSocket.CloseOutputAsync(code, reason, _connectionAbortedToken);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task SendMessageAsync(WebSocketMessageType type, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> data)
        {
            if (_webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                return;
            }

            await _webSocket.SendAsync(data, type, endOfMessage: true, _connectionAbortedToken);
        }

        public void Close(WebSocketCloseStatus code, string? reason)
        {
            if (_closeBlock.Completion.IsCompleted)
            {
                return;
            }

            _ = _closeBlock.Post((code, reason));

            _sendBlock.Complete();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _sendingAbortedCts.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```csharp
// Inside Startup.cs

app.Run(async context =>
{
    if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        return;
    }

    var webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

    using var connection = new DataflowWebSocketConnection(
        webSocket,
        maxReceivedMessageSize: 8 * 1024,
        context.RequestAborted);

    var utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);

    // Echo whatever the client sends in reverse.
    var echoBlock = new TransformBlock<
        (WebSocketMessageType Type, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Data),
        (WebSocketMessageType Type, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Data)>(
        message =>
        {
            if (message.Type == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            {
                message.Data = utf8Encoding.GetBytes(
                    new string(utf8Encoding.GetString(message.Data.Span).Reverse().ToArray()));
            }

            return message;
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded });

    using var link1 = connection.Input.LinkTo(echoBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    using var link2 = echoBlock.LinkTo(connection.Output, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    // Send a greeting message to the client.
    _ = connection.Output.Post((WebSocketMessageType.Text, utf8Encoding.GetBytes("Greetings!")));

    // Close the connection after 20 seconds.
    var closeAfter20SecondsTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

        connection.Close(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Bye-bye!");
    });

    await connection.Closure;

    await closeAfter20SecondsTask;
});
```

I have played around with this implementation a bit and it seems to do what it is supposed to, but because I'm not very experienced with TPL Dataflow I'd like to know if there are any problems or caveats with this design that I should be aware of, especially when it comes to thread safety.

If there are any general improvements to code clarity or the design of the class that I could make I would also love to hear.